# Отключение рендера объекта, находящегося за другим объектом

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня возникла проблема, связанная с тем, что область камеры пронизывает насквозь все объекты, а значит рендерит даже те из них, которые по факту не видны по причине того, что перекрыты другими объектами. Как можно эту проблему устранить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы смотрите на объект из камеры редактора, а не из камеры сцены, поэтому видите его. Движок сам решает, что рендерить а что нет и оптимизирует отрисовку, в зависимости от используемой камеры на уровне полигонов. Другими словами, проблемы, описанной в вопросе, попросту не существует.

Comment: Я знаю, просто описал наглядно проблему

Comment: Я руководствуюсь тем, что мне выдавало окно stats. Я смотрел через ИГРОВУЮ камеру на куб, за которым есть ещё кубы. И исходя из того, что было выведено в графе "Shadow casters", я и делаю вывод, что все кубы ниже тоже рендерятся

Comment: Само собой рендерятся, они отбрасывают тени, отражения и т.д. То что прямой луч из камеры не попадает в объект - это не значит что не попадёт отраженный. Предполагаю, что такие оптимизации можно настраивать с помощью шейдеров.

Comment: А можно ли ограничить возможности камеры? Например: Если "Лучи" камеры столкнулись с объектом, то дальше они не пойдут?

Comment: Да, вы можете написать кастомный пайплайн рендерера/шейдеры и т.д.

Comment: Ну... Это в любом случае неплохая наводка, правда я ещё новичок. Мне, думаю, до Шейдеров ещё далеко. Попробую в Asset store поискать что-нибудь годное.

Comment: Совет: вероятные тормоза движка базово устраняются настройками рендера, без переписываний и т.д. Я бы на вашем месте больше бы уделял внимания написанию высокопроизводительных скриптов, расширенному изучению C# в конце концов. Если опыта мало - это в сотни раз важнее, чем переживать раньше времени за внутренности 3D движка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эта техника оптимизации называется Oclussion Culling. Unity поддерживает из коробки эту технику и ее можно включить довольно просто:

1. настроить объекты (static occluder и static ocludee)
2. сгенерировать граф oclussion tree

Более детально весь процесс [тут](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/working-with-occlusion-culling#5fe2b352edbc2a10f945f216)